# laravel 5.5 Necesito incluir una variable dentro de un array tipo json

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Necesito incluir $token dentro del array $user en donde guardo mi consulta, estoy usando el framework laravel 5.5

```
 protected function respondWithToken($token,$documento){
    $user = User::select('id','nombre','email')->where('documento', $documento)->get();

     $token =  [
         'access_token' => $token,
         'token_type' => 'bearer'
     ];


    return $user;

}
```

Se que puedo juntar y concatenar dentro de una función array pero quedaría así, y no es la manera que busco. Deseo incluirlo dentro de un solo array.

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Pedro",
            "email": "Gonzalez@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "token": "sfgt854dfgdf54dfg5df4gdf98g4df",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

necesito incluir esa variable token dentro de mi objeto y retorne un json de esta manera

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Pedro",
        "email": "Gonzalez@gmail.com",
        "token": "sdjkfhsdk65468541sdf3"

    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola para ese tipo de casos es bueno usar `compact`

```
protected function respondWithToken($token,$documento){
    $user = User::select('id','nombre','email')->where('documento', $documento)->get();
    $token_type = 'bearer';
    $conjunto_variables = compact('user','token','token_type ');

    return $conjunto_variables ;

}
```

> Que hace **compact**?

Bueno compact en términos simples crea un array con variables y sus valores, es muy útil si quieres enviar muchas variables a la vez y poder llamarlas en la vista o donde la retornas.

Su funcionamiento se basa principalmente en que el nombre de la variable queda como llave para llamarlo. Ejemplo: en tu compact hice que que `user` es el nombre de tu variable , bueno con ese mismo nombre la puedes llamar en otra parte así `$user` ,ya que lo retorné en ese compact y lo mismo puedo hacer con el resto de las variables.

> PD: para que funcione el compact tiene que estar entre comillas y
>   tener en nombre de la variable no otra. Espero te sirva .Saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $user = User::select('id','nombre','email')->where('documento', $documento)->first()->toArray(); 
//first en vez de get

     $token =  [
         'access_token' => $token,
         'token_type' => 'bearer'
     ];


    return json_encode($user + $token);
```

Gracias a adolfo abegg jajaja

Comment: que buena solución Fran :)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo mas sencillo es añadir el indice que quieres al array $user:

```
$user['token'] = $token['access_token']
```

En el caso de que $user sea un array, siempre puedes acceder al primer elemento (entiendo que aunque sea un array solo estas buscando un usuario) y hacer lo mismo:

```
$user[0]['token'] = $token['access_token']
```